# Next.js 14.1: Error 500 in production after successful build and start

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth

I have a Next.js 14.1 application that works perfectly in development mode (`npm run dev`), but encounters a 500 Internal Server Error in production after running `next build` (which completes successfully) and `next start`. When trying to access any page, including "/", the following error is returned:

```
 Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clientModules')
    at /Users/daniele/Documents/informagica/digimon-browser-game/digimon-browser-game/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:199008
    at rW (/Users/daniele/Documents/informagica/digimon-browser-game/digimon-browser-game/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:16:14861)
    at nM (/Users/daniele/Documents/informagica/digimon-browser-game/digimon-browser-game/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:47419)
    at nN (/Users/daniele/Documents/informagica/digimon-browser-game/digimon-browser-game/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
    at nM (/Users/daniele/Documents/informagica/digimon-browser-game/digimon-browser-game/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:61233)
    at nN (/Users/daniele/Documents/informagica/digimon-browser-game/digimon-browser-game/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
    at nI (/Users/daniele/Documents/informagica/digimon-browser-game/digimon-browser-game/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:46806)
    at nM (/Users/daniele/Documents/informagica/digimon-browser-game/digimon-browser-game/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:47570)
    at nN (/Users/daniele/Documents/informagica/digimon-browser-game/digimon-browser-game/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
    at nM (/Users/daniele/Documents/informagica/digimon-browser-game/digimon-browser-game/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:61233)
```

Additionally, my application uses Next-Auth (^4.24.6) for authentication. I've observed that if I remove the session check from the "/" page (i.e., `const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);`), the error changes.

I have checked the build logs, and everything seems to be in order. Any insights into why this error is occurring in the production environment despite a successful build would be greatly appreciated. Furthermore, if there are any specific considerations or configurations needed when deploying a Next.js 14.1 app using Next-Auth in a production environment, please provide guidance.

Comment: which next-auth version? 4 or 5

Comment: next-auth 4, I've updated the question